# QT Creator doesn't automatically add the closing curly bracket after while, for, if and else if statements

Tags: qt, qt-creator, brackets, curly-braces

I've been tinkering with qt creator but it seems I must've missed the setting which enables this feature which is included in every other IDE out there. Essentially after an if, else if, for or while statement's condition, I press enter and automatically indents and after inserting the left curly bracket it doesn't automatically add the right one. Is it possible to enable a setting to automatically add the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found out the closing bracket is automatically added after pressing enter. I hope this helps anyone facing the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable or disable this feature from:

Tools -> Options... -> Text Editor -> Completion -> Automatically insert brackets

Answer (score 0):

For the QtCreator 10.0.0, it is under Edit/Preferences.../Text Editor/Completion/ Automatically insert matching characters/ Insert opening or closing brackets.